# How to improve performance with executeBatch?

Tags: java, jdbc

I am writing Java code for inserting 45000 records into the table
and I'm using the following code:

```
//create Db Connection
List<String> sqlInsertQueries = getListOfInsertsQueries();
for (String currentsql : sqlInsertQueries)
{
  stmt.addBatch(currentsql);
}
stmt.executeBatch();
conn.commit();
```

This code is very slow and it takes almost 5 minutes to be finished.

Is there any idea how to make it work faster?

Answer (score 16):

You should make sure that auto commit is false, and use prepared statements.
Prepared statements can be used for insert and update.

```
connection con.setAutoCommit(false);  
PreparedStatement prepStmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO table (val1,val2) VALUES (?,?)");

for all values:
  prepStmt.setString(1,val1);
  prepStmt.setString(2,val2);
  prepStmt.addBatch();    

stmt.executeBatch(); 
conn.commit();
```

Comment: I would also insert commit statements every 1000 inserts if it is ok from a business point to have partial inserts since the write ahead log might get too big

Comment: specail Thanks now it took l0 seconds,but why it;s big differnt between prepare Statement and regular statment?

Comment: Also, make sure you're using a new version of the JDBC driver and add &rewriteBatchedStatements=true to the connection string.    More good tips: http://assets.en.oreilly.com/1/event/21/Connector_J%20Performance%20Gems%20Presentation.pdf

Comment: look here for an explanation of performance difference http://webmoli.com/2008/10/23/back-to-basics-statement-vs-prepared-statement/