# MySql Batch insertion - Disk usage 100% on Windows 10 Task Manager

Tags: mysql, performance

I am trying insert multiple rows using MySQL Batch Prepared Statement.

I am testing on local machine: Windows 10 with MySQL Server 8.0 and Eclipse Photon.

When the code starts the batch, my laptop performance slow down. Looking at TaskManager I realize that the Disk Usage goes to 100%.

If I stop the running on Eclipse, the Disk Usage normalize and the performance issues is gone. It happens always I am trying to run my code.

I am not sure if the problem is my code or it is my laptop because I have the same issuing when turning on my laptop, starting windows with mysql. I need to wait some minutes until my disk usage become normal and I start to use my laptop.

```
private static final String CONNECTION_STRING = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/parser?user=root&password=root&useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC";

MySQLAccess(boolean debug) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    connect = DriverManager
            .getConnection(CONNECTION_STRING);

    isDebug = debug;
}

private void insertLogTable(List<Map<String, Object>> logList) throws SQLException{
    String sql = "INSERT INTO log (date, ip, request, status, userAgent) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    PreparedStatement ps = connect.prepareStatement(sql);

    int i = 0;
    for (Map<String, Object> log : logList) {

        ps.setString(1, getMySQLDateString((Date)log.get("date")));
        ps.setString(2, (String)log.get("ip"));
        ps.setString(3, (String)log.get("request"));
        ps.setString(4, (String)log.get("status"));
        ps.setString(5, (String)log.get("userAgent"));

        ps.addBatch();
        i++;

        if (i % 1000 == 0 || i == logList.size()) {
            ps.executeBatch(); // Execute every 1000 items.
            debug(getMySQLDateString((Date)log.get("date")));
        }
    }

    ps.close();
}

public void close() {
    try {
        if (connect != null) {
            connect.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Edit:

I ran "SELECT @@innodb_buffer_pool_size" and got '8388608'.

My laptop has 8GB of Ram Memory.

```
CREATE TABLE `log` (
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `request` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `userAgent` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `logcol` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `logcol1` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ip_index` (`ip`),
  KEY `date_index` (`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=915169 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4     COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

RESOLVED: I solved this problem following this question [How to improve performance with executeBatch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150165/how-to-improve-performance-with-executebatch)

Comment: Can you show us a sample _completed_ `INSERT`?  And `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  The indexes are an important part of the figuring out your question.  How much RAM?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Comment: @RickJames, I edited my post including more information. I did not understand your question "sample completed INSERT".

Comment: The code you presented is in Java?/Eclipse?  I would like to see the SQL that it generates.

Comment: @RickJames, yes, it is Java. And I am using Eclipse.

The SQL command I am using is only what you can see in the code snippet above:

String sql = "INSERT INTO log (date, ip, request, status, userAgent) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

Comment: Well, I _suspect_ that `addBatch` leads to a "batched" insert, wherein it builds a long `INSERT` string with 1K rows, then executes it.  If it is not batched, then the analysis in my answer needs some changes.

Comment: I solved my problem following this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150165/how-to-improve-performance-with-executebatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `my.cnf` change to

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4G
```

for your 8GB machine.  Then restart mysql.

The tiny 8M setting you currently have leads to significant I/O due to lack of cache in RAM.

(If 4G is too big for the other things running, pick some other number, but try at least 300M.)

I'm surprised that Win 10 will run in only 8G.

I'm surprised that version 8.0 started out with a tiny 8M.  Did you inherit that setting from long ago (when 8M was the default)?  I think version 5.5 bumped the default to 128M in the year 2010!

More analysis:

The index on `ip` probably occupies 40MB or so.  And, I assume, the IP addresses come in rather randomly?  Each time a new row is inserted, the index for `ip` is updated.  That is, one block (16KB in size) of the 40MB is fetched, modified, and stored back to disk.  Assuming random access and 40MB:8MB, then 80% of the time this fetch-modify-write requires hitting the disk.  That is, for every clump of 1000 rows, there are 800*2 disk hits *just for the `ip` index*.  Also, there will be some number (a smaller number) of hits for the 'sequentially' written data and other indexes.  I would guess about 20*1 more disk hits.

That is just a crude calculation.  But it points out that if your buffer_pool were more than 40MB (let's say at least 100MB, to allow for various factors I did not mention), then virtually all the I/O would vanish.  Everything would stay cached, hence no need for the "fetches".  And the "writes" can be delayed and not have to be re-done.

Comment: I updated innodb_buffer_pool_size to 4G and it do not solve. I restarted mysql and Windows.

After, I tried to remove the indexes before insert the records ( I will recrete then after that) but it also did not work.

I will try to test on Linux.

Comment: In case the "batch" is really one at a time, try `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2` and restart.